# Why are the functions not going through and working (together)?

Tags: python, list, function, loops, module

I have to create 2 functions:

function 1 checks if all integers in a list are unique (from function 2)

function 2: generates the random list of numbers with a given range

main function: has all the inputs of range and how many integers the user wants to generate.

MY QUESTION: I tried examining my code multiple times but I can't tell why nothing is printing...

```
import random
#check for all unique values in list
def allunique(x):
    unique_or_not= []
    for item in x:
        if item in unique_or_not:
            return False
        unique_or_not.append(item)
    return True

#generate list of random numbers
def list_of_nums(start,end,number_of_values):
    for i in range(0,number_of_values):
        nums= []
        nums.append(random.randint(start,end))
    return nums


#main function of inputs and calls list
def main():
    number_of_values= int(input("Please enter the number of values you wish to generate:"))
    start= int(input("Please enter the starting # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    end= int(input("Please enter the ending # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    myList= list_of_nums(start,end, number_of_values)
    print(myList)

main()
```

Comment: Nothing calls your `main()` function, but you do call `list_of_nums()` with no arguments, which should immediately raise a `TypeError` since that function takes two arguments.  I suspect the code you pasted here is not the code you're running -- did you forget to save the file?

Comment: that was a mistake, thank you, I call main but for some reason it still doesn't output a list

Comment: Instead of prompting for user input, write canned parameters for `list_of_nums`. The goal is self-contained example scripts that are easier for us to run.

Answer (score 0):

**Changes made:-**

(1) Intialisation of `nums=[]` before the `for` loop. **cause every time for loop iterates it intialize** nums to `[]` **(i.e empty list)**.

**Code:-**

```
import random
#check for all unique values in list
def allunique(x):
    unique_or_not= []
    for item in x:
        if item in unique_or_not:
            return False
        unique_or_not.append(item)
    return True

#generate list of random numbers
def list_of_nums(start,end,number_of_values):
    nums= []
    for i in range(0,number_of_values):
        nums.append(random.randint(start,end))
    return nums


#main function of inputs and calls list
def main():
    number_of_values= int(input("Please enter the number of values you wish to generate:"))
    start= int(input("Please enter the starting # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    end= int(input("Please enter the ending # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    myList= list_of_nums(start,end, number_of_values)
    print(myList)

main()
```

**Output:-**

```
Please enter the number of values you wish to generate:3
Please enter the starting # of the values you wish to generate:2
Please enter the ending # of the values you wish to generate:10
[5, 4, 2]
```